# How do you proof data from an SQL-Query for completeness and validity?

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I'm searching for scientific methods to proof the returned data of an SQL-Query for completeness and validity.

For example if i query for all records which meet 3 defined conditions, how can i proof that this query really returns the right records and all of them?

The amount of data is too big to proof it manually.

Comment: You just pray for the right data. And some unit tests might be useful too (http://tsqlt.org/ is one of them but I guess there is plenty more)

Comment: Why do so many people keep tagging both `mysql` and `sql-server`? Does anybody even read the pop-ups for the tags they're choosing?

Comment: simple explanation for this, these 2 tags where added automatically.

Comment: "suggested tags" are just suggestions from an algorithm. You don't have to accept the suggestion. Choose the tags that make sense.

Answer (score 2):

You must proof your query on a constructed DB with records entered manually for this purpose. You should include records that represent all possible combinations of cases relevant for this query. Then determine what the expected outputs for your query for different test cases should be and compare them with the actual result.

For 3 conditions, where each one can be TRUE or FALSE, you get 2^3 = 8 possible outcomes. If some fields can be NULL, make sure to test those cases as well. If you test for TRUE, FALSE and NULL you might get 3^3 = 27 test cases. This number can increase rapidly if you include more corner cases.

See [Three-valued logic - Application in SQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-valued_logic#Application_in_SQL),
           [MySQL Logical Operators](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/logical-operators.html),
           [SQL-Server Nullability and Three-Value Logic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131081.aspx) Comparisons

The ideal case is when the specifications you got from your customer include examples. Try to reproduce these examples.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * from table_name 
WHERE column1 is not NULL 
AND column2 is not NULL 
AND column3 is not NULL;
```

If the above query gives any result then both of three columns have complete values without any null.